# PostgreSQL 9.5: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

I have staging and main table. Using staging table I am updating main table
Below are inputs and expected output for reference and I have written query but not sure why its not updating duplicate records and throwing error

> ```
> ERROR: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed.
> ```

Below example is just for illustration purposes. I gave actual data on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ERYqnzUT).

stg

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |
| 4 | Value 4 | null |

main

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 5 | null |
| 1 | Value 5 | null |
| 2 | Value 8 | null |
| 2 | Value 8 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |

Expected Output :

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |

I have tried below query but it's not working as expected. I'm getting the error `multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed`. For some reason, it's working on fiddle.

```sql
UPDATE test   
SET val=s.val,updated=s.updated 
FROM (select distinct s1.val,
             s1.updated
      from stg s1,
           test t1 
      WHERE t1.id=s1.id a)s;
```

If any experts can help how to write the query with this scenario, please do.

Comment: So your main table is actually named test? Don't use correlated subquery. The WHERE clause should probably be outside the parens.

Comment: Because you are not correlating `test` and `stg` on `id` for the actual update, so you are repeating the update for each row in `test` for every row in `stg`.  See the examples here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html), in particular the section under *Update contact names in an accounts table to match the currently assigned salespeople: ...*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: @June7 : I have used the above example as my data and table is similar to that...Test is just sample name i have created for my question here.

Comment: @Test can you paste what you get when you run `select version();` on your database? Isn't it actually Greenplum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Update is wrong.

you find in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) how it should be

```
UPDATE main m
SET "val" = s."val" , "updated" = s."updated"
FROM stg s
WHERE s."Id" = m."Id"
```

> ```
> UPDATE 5
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM main
```

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pulNAsjZ)

When ID, val and updated are the same you can use

```
UPDATE main m
SET "val" = s."val" , "updated" = s."updated"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "Id", "val", "updated" FROM  stg) s
WHERE s."Id" = m."Id"
```

> ```
> UPDATE 5
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM main
```

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7blrXY5T)

another approach is to use window functions

```
UPDATE main m
SET "val" = s."val" , "updated" = s."updated"
FROM (WITH CTE as (SELECT  "Id", "val", "updated" ,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Id" ORDER BY "updated" DESC) rn FROM  stg)
  SELECT "Id", "val", "updated" FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1) s
WHERE s."Id" = m."Id"
```

> ```
> UPDATE 5
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM main
```

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 3 | Value 3 | null |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RAt1xXHW)

Comment: As main table contains duplicate records although fiddle is giving the correct output but unfortunately query is still giving me the same error.multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed.Is there way to update it in any other way so that will not this error.

Comment: is is always the same  updated in src for the same id?

Comment: i have added the distinct subselect, but maybe you should provide some better data

Comment: @nbk-Yes,if the main table(test) has duplicate record same val will be populated from stg for both rows.

Comment: @nbk-On my db above query throwing error s."id" doesn't exist. I will share more relevant data.

Comment: I have replicated the scenario in fiddle with actual data that I have .If you can please help https://dbfiddle.uk/ERYqnzUT

Comment: i think you should read some sql books, about aloas see https://dbfiddle.uk/tZqlwrx8

Comment: @nbk-Thank you but its throwing same error :ERROR: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed  not sure why in my db

Comment: try this one instead i didn't belive from the start that distinct would word https://dbfiddle.uk/oZVcQqED

Comment: Thank you @nbk...you are genius.this logic works for 98% of my scenarios..I have just observed that for some cases I may get 2 records with same subject_id,wf_id,instance_id,session_id but there could be different mapping name or session name associated with that etc...in that case the value with max update date is picking up and as an end result i am getting duplicate records because for both of them it updated the max value one.. not sure if there  is way to handle those in query.

Comment: you can take the cte and manipulate it, and see what values are returned and of course the join it will need more fine-tuning depending on tje real data, but now you now how to get your wanted result